# Derivative of Product of Matrix with Moore-Penrose Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Assume that $A(x) \in M_{m,n}$ is given and depends on some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $A^\dagger(x) = [A(x)^\star A(x)]^{-1} A^\star(x)$ be the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A(x)$.

Define $G(x) = A(x) A^\dagger(x)$ and derive the derivative $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$.

My steps so far (trying to exploit that $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \text{vec}\ G(x)}{\partial x}$:
$$
   G(x) = A(x) [A(x)^\star A(x)]^{-1} A^\star(x) \\
   \iff \text{vec}(G(x)) = \text{vec}(A(x) [A(x)^\star A(x)]^{-1} A^\star(x)) \\
    = (A(x) \otimes A(x)) \text{vec}([A(x)^\star A(x)]^{-1})
$$
where $C \otimes D$ is the Kronecker product of $C$ and $D$.

Comment: I think you have the wrong definition of pseudoinverse

Comment: I think it is the correct one, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) _Definition_

Comment: Does $A(x)$ have linearly independent columns?  If not, then your formula for the pseuoinverse is incorrect because the inverse of $A(x)^{*}A(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: it does, thanks for the remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=\frac{dA}{dx}$. By the product rule and the rule that $dY^{-1}=-Y^{-1}(dY)Y^{-1}$, we obtain
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dG}{dx}=\frac{dAA^\dagger}{dx}
&=BA^\dagger+A\left[-(A^\ast A)^{-1}(B^\ast A+A^\ast B)(A^\ast A)^{-1}A^\ast+(A^\ast A)^{-1}B^\ast\right]\\
&=BA^\dagger-(A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast AA^\dagger - (A^\dagger)^\ast A^\ast BA^\dagger+ (A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast\\
&=BA^\dagger-(A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast G - G^\ast BA^\dagger+ (A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast\\
&=(I-G)^\ast BA^\dagger+(A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast(I-G)\\
&=(I-G)BA^\dagger+(A^\dagger)^\ast B^\ast(I-G)^\ast\\
&=(I-G)BA^\dagger+\left[(I-G)BA^\dagger\right]^\ast.
\end{aligned}

Sanity checks:

- As $G$ is Hermitian, $\frac{dG}{dx}$ should also be Hermitian.
- As $GA=AA^\ast A=A$, we have $\frac{dG}{dx}A+G\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac{dA}{dx}$. Hence $\frac{dG}{dx}A$ should be equal to $(I-G)B$.

Comment: thanks for the great answer! Would you mind adding some comments with respect to the first step? There is a lot going on there :)

Answer (score 1):

If any solutions of the linear system $BA=C$ exist, they are given by $$B = CA^+ + R(I-G)$$ where $G=AA^+,\,$ $I$ is the identity matrix, and $R$ is an arbitrary matrix.

For ease of typing, use $\,dA=\frac{dA}{dx}$

Differentiating the first Penrose condition yields

$$\eqalign{
A &= GA \\
dA &= d(GA) = dG\,A + G\,dA \\
dG\,A &= (I-G)\,dA \\
dG &= (I-G)\,dA\,A^+ + R(I-G) \\
}$$
Since $(dG,I,G)$ are hermitian, we can identify $R$ 
to complete the solution.
$$\eqalign{
dG^* &= dG \quad\implies\quad R^* = dA\,A^+ \\
dG &= (I-G)\,dA\,A^+  + (dA\,A^+)^*(I-G) \\
}$$